# Qt Background Image for window show black screen

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll

first of all i'm new in qt, and then in my project i try to set background image for window with resource file, for this work i used from this code :

```
ui->setupUi(this);

QPixmap bkgnd(":/img/img/auto4.jpg");
int widWidth = this->width();
int widHeight = this->height();
bkgnd = bkgnd.scaled(widWidth, widHeight, Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding);
QPalette palette;
palette.setBrush(QPalette::Background, bkgnd);
this->setPalette(palette);
```

after build, in debug mode or when i open exe file in my system all is correct and work perfectly !

but when i move file to other system, i just see a black window !!!
for move and run into new system i move only exe file and qt dll, here is list of all file in new system !

```
Autorun.exe
libEGL.dll
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Network.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
```

so i want to know whats wrong ? why only work in my system and show black window in other system ?

Comment: 1) does the other system have the image file? 2) is the image file in the expected location on the orher system? 3) those explicit dereferences of `this` are completely unnecessary and just add noise.

Comment: @JesperJuhl : thanks for your ans, i think when i use from resource file we dont need to copy image file,(at last in C# we don't need) so i dont cope/move image to other system ! and if need to copy so how can i set new location for load image from that (in new system we have a new location) ? thanks and kind regards.

Comment: Well, is the resource file on the other system? Does it contain the image? Have you considered adding some error checking to your code to find out where it goes wrong? Considered running it in a debugger to see what's going on? - I mean; have you done the most basic of debugging of this *at all*?

Comment: @JesperJuhl OP is referring to the Qt Resource System. Those are binary resources embedded in the executable itself. Their purpose is precisely not to have to distribute any files with the executable.

Comment: @KubaOber Thnx. -  after check i find this error : `Pixmap is a null pixmap` but i don't know why ! i was checked with many path (with/without  alias,prefix,//,/,etc) but dont work !!! all path only work in my system !!! REALY WHY ?

Comment: May be, the image could not be loaded as the necessary image importer is not on the other system. Though, the image binary data might be embedded in the executable the resp. image loader will be needed to decode it into a `QImage` or `QPixmap`. Have a look at Qt docs.: [Qt Image Formats](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimageformats-index.html). Deploy is mentioned near the end which I guess is relevant in your case.

Comment: In your specific case, it could help to provide additionally a folder `imageformats` containing `qjpeg.dll`. (You should find it somewhere in your Qt directory.) I'm not quite sure whether the folder is necessary. (I just looked into a binary dir. of one of our recent release builds.) Might be, that it is required so that your Qt appl. can locate the plug-in properly. You may try out if it works without the folder as well (i.e. storing `qjepg.dll` in the same folder as `Autorun.exe`).

Comment: I don't see qt plugin for jpeg in files that you are moving.

Comment: @Scheff ,Thanks but after try i see that is not work ! :(

Comment: It probably does not work if you store `qjpeg.dll` in the same folder than `Autorun.exe`. I just had a look into one of our self-made _and_ installed Qt appl. It provides the image plug-ins in a sub-sub-folder `plugins\imageformats` (i.e. `plugins\imageformats\qjpeg.dll`). (Don't know why it was different in our release-built folder...) However, this is worth a try as it works in our case. (Otherwise, our testers and customers surely had complained about this.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff , I try with a new project, I do all work again and finally work perfectly ! (however in old project i don't know why but after rebuild that's not work again , that is not important i can create new project and copy all code to new project !) , finally you solved my problem thanks